# What FlushModeType does spring's @Transactional use?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

I understand the default `FlushMode` with hibernate is `AUTO` when the session is used directly.

I have not been able to figure out what the `FlushMode` type is when Spring's `@Transactional` is used instead. My guess would be the `COMMIT` as it would not make sense otherwise because `@Transactional` is meant to commit the transaction when the annotated method exits.

Can someone please advise?

Reference to source code or official documentation would be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring does not change the default configuration, so it is `AUTO`.

Flush mode affects when the changes from the persistence context are written to the database, committing those changes is quite another thing and happens at the end of the transaction (regardless of when the changes were flushed to the db prior to committing them).

Comment: I understand better now. Thanks